# Having issues finding the symbol?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is the code line that I'm currently using and have the same error on multiple lines that has same error:

```
response.getHeaders().add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Access to the Website\"");
```

Here's the error that I'm currently getting:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getHeaders()
  location: variable response of type javax.ws.rs.core.Response
```

Here are the dependencies that I'm currently using for the project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.genesys.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>17.36.5</version>
    <name>Genesys Cloud Automation</name>
    <description>Tool for automating rapid deployment of Genesys Ecosystems</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.18.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>4.2.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <org.apache.tomcat.version>7.0.84</org.apache.tomcat.version>
        <org.apache.cxf.version>3.3.3</org.apache.cxf.version>
        <org.apache.http.version>4.5.2</org.apache.http.version>
        <org.apache.http.core.version>4.4.9</org.apache.http.core.version>
        <org.apache.commons.version>3.0</org.apache.commons.version>
        <org.apache.commons.codec.version>1.9</org.apache.commons.codec.version>
        <org.apache.commons.collections.version>4.1</org.apache.commons.collections.version>
        <org.apache.commons.exec.version>1.3</org.apache.commons.exec.version>
        <org.apache.commons.net.version>3.3</org.apache.commons.net.version>
        <org.apache.commons.xmlbeans.version>2.3.0</org.apache.commons.xmlbeans.version>
        <org.apache.poi.version>3.7</org.apache.poi.version>
        <com.fasterxml.uuid>3.1.4</com.fasterxml.uuid>
        <org.codehaus.jackson.version>1.9.13</org.codehaus.jackson.version>
        <com.genesyslab.platform.version>900.6.1</com.genesyslab.platform.version>
        <com.genesyslab.gax.version>9.0.100.44</com.genesyslab.gax.version>
        <gax.opm.arm-version>8.1.400.38</gax.opm.arm-version>
        <com.genesyslab.gax-rdt.version>9.0.100-44</com.genesyslab.gax-rdt.version>
        <microsoft.jdbc.version>4.0</microsoft.jdbc.version>
        <com.cedarsoftware.version>1.8.0</com.cedarsoftware.version>
        <ch.qos.logback.version>1.0.13</ch.qos.logback.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
        <javax.mail.version>1.6.0</javax.mail.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2</cglib.version>
        <com.squareup.okhttp.version>2.7.1</com.squareup.okhttp.version>
        <jre.version>1.8</jre.version>
        <com.opencsv.version>4.1</com.opencsv.version>
        <mina.version>1.1.7</mina.version>
        <sshd.version>1.7.0</sshd.version>
    </properties>
    
   <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.100</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--jcifs dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20150729</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.exec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.net.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${org.codehaus.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-util</artifactId>
            <version>${com.cedarsoftware.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mina.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
            <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
            <version>${sshd.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.commons.xmlbeans.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId> 
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId> 
            <version>${com.opencsv.version}</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.genesyslab.gax</groupId>
            <artifactId>gax-common</artifactId>
            <version>${com.genesyslab.gax.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.genesyslab.gax</groupId>
            <artifactId>gax-core</artifactId>
            <version>${com.genesyslab.gax.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.genesyslab.gax</groupId>
            <artifactId>gax-opm-arm</artifactId>
            <version>${gax.opm.arm-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.genesyslab.gax</groupId>
            <artifactId>gax-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>${com.genesyslab.gax.version}</version>
        </dependency>





        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.genesyslab.gax</groupId>
            <artifactId>gax-rdt</artifactId>
            <version>${com.genesyslab.gax-rdt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.uuid}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.http.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.http.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${com.squareup.okhttp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mypurecloud/platform-client-v2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mypurecloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-client-v2</artifactId>
            <version>112.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>        
         </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3-transfer-manager</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.103-PREVIEW</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jre.version}</source>
                    <target>${jre.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.genesys.cloud.automation.GenesysCloudAutomation</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
                <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <onejarversion>0.97</onejarversion>
                            <classifier>onejar</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>one-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>app.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>app.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

What am I currently doing wrong and the best possible solution to get the error resolve

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Can you show you project dependencies/versions and imports?

Comment: The versions of your dependencies are not clear from the provided pom.xml fragment.

Comment: Added the whole thing this time; sorry about that

Comment: Check the module dependencies diagram, `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` is coming from 1.x version which doesn't have `getHeaders()` method. You need to use 2.x+ version for that.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA [Maven dependencies diagram](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_dependency_diagram) can help you to find where `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` version 1 lacking `getHeaders()` method is coming from:

[image: Diagram]

The solution would be to move `mssql-jdbc` dependency to the bottom in `pom.xml` so that `jersey-core` has lower priority than `jakarta.ws.rs-api` dependency (these 2 dependencies are providing the same `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` class, but different versions of it).

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
```